# Соединиться с сайтом средствами JS?

Tags: javascript

Всем хорошего настроения.

есть сайт `site.ru/test.php`  в файле `test.php` записана цифра `1` и **больше ничего в нем нет**.

Как на `JS` соединяться с этой страницей и получить ее содержимое в переменную **без открытия самой странице в окне браузере**?

Comment: ajax? (еще 8 символов нужно..)

Comment: @Moonvvell не только чистий JS

Comment: Это технология асинхронных запросов JavaScript :)

Comment: @Анатолий, технология AJAX на чистом JS выполняется через [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest). Более современная альтернатива для новых браузеров [метод fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), но учтите, он сырой и к примеру IE его не поддерживает.

Comment: Я макрос пишу, он у меня работает в firefox на чистом js

Comment: XMLHttpRequest и fetch присутствуют в фаерфоксе

Comment: стоит пометить, что средствами js вы сможете получить только возвращаемые сервером данные, а не исходные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из самых современных способов сделать такой запрос это [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
fetch('http://httpbin.org/get?param=value')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

```js
fetch('http://httpbin.org/get?param=value')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Поддержка в браузерах(IE/Safari) пока не очень, но наличие рабочих полифиллов позволяет не отказывать себе в этом удовольствии.

---

Также стоит упомянуть, что я выбрал для демонстрации `httpbin.org` неспроста. Он разрешает кроссдоменные запросы(CORS) передавая в ответе пару заголовков:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null
```

Без этого, браузер бы не позволил `javascript` получить ответ от сайта с доменом, отличным от того, на котором выполняется скрипт.
Эта политика безопасности была разработана, чтобы у вредоносных скриптов не было возможности обращаться от вашего имени к сервисам, которыми они не владеют.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду пробовать.

Comment: Кажется работает но как в алерт вывести то что на странице, там чисто только цифра 1 написана.

Comment: `json` на `text` замените. Вот тут можно подробнее почитать: [js.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

Comment: Чето я совсем не разобрался, делаю так var test = response.text();
alert(test); Ошибку выдает.

Comment: Посмотри внимательно на ответ выше, `response.text()` возвращает `Promise`, нужен ещё один `.then`

Comment: Добавил вариант без стрелочных функций, если непривычно.

Comment: Я синтаксиса не могу написать пишу уже так alert( this.responseText ); пишет что не найдено. Мне в переменную нужно получить единицу ту что в документы, как это сделать.

Comment: ну вот, в коде выше в переменной `data` и будет твоя единица

Comment: Спасибо, уже понял. Благодарю, если что и звените чайника :)